# JS function setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm JS beginner and was trying to understand setTimeout function.
So idea is to create something like timer with input time.
but its not working, saying idiot() is not defined.

Edit #1: my bad, seems like typo in function syntax, but setTimeout is not working anyway.
My idea is basically when you click button **function idiot()** will start will keep deducting -1 from from **time** variable with 1sec delay. So like timer.

```js
funtion idiot() {
  let time = document.getElementById("time").value;
  time--
  timeShow = document.getElementById("eblan");
  timeShow.innerHTML = time
}
setTimeout(idiot, 1000)
```

```html
<input type="number" id="time"></input>
<button onclick="idiot()">click</button>
<div id="eblan">time</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Mavlyanov seems typo, since you are beginner it is always a best practice to directly test your function(with hardcoded values if any) through debug console or IDE debugger just to see if it is working that will rule out your first level of errors.

Comment: @AshishJain thanks! Will start doing it in right way from this moment!

Answer (score 0):

```
funtion idiot() {
  let time = document.getElementById("time").value;
  time--
  timeShow = document.getElementById("eblan");
  timeShow.innerHTML = time
}
```

This seems to be a simple spelling mistake.
`funtion` should be spelled `function`

Comment: Thanks!  My bad, was doing it on codepen and there no autocorrect. But setTimeout not working anyway :(

Answer (score 0):

First you have a typo in first line you typed `funtion` instead of `function`

second, if you want the timeout to start when the user click on function you should create a new function which sets the timeout and then call it when user click the button

an example would be  :

```
function idiot() {
  let time =document.getElementById("time").value;
  time--
  timeShow = document.getElementById("eblan");
  timeShow.innerHTML = time
  document.getElementById("time").value = time; // Remove this if you want to display the same value all the time
}


function timedIdiot() {
    setTimeout(idiot, 1000)
}
```

and for your html

```html
<input type="number" id="time"></input>
<button onclick="timedIdiot()">click</button>
<div id="eblan">time</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Really embarassing asking such questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setTimeout` with `time` value and invoke it after 1 second and decrement the value of time in the callback.

```js
function idiot() {
  let time = document.getElementById("time").value;
  runTimer(time);
}

function runTimer(time) {
  document.getElementById("eblan").innerHTML = time;
  if(time > 0) {
    setTimeout(() => runTimer(--time), 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="time"></input>
<button onclick="idiot()">click</button>
<div id="eblan">time</div>
```

Comment: Yeah! Its working! Thank you, now i need to understand why there blank function in () => . Thanks, man!

Comment: That is [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval()` to update the timer. Otherwise use a recursive function to update until timer is `0`.